# Parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup and no Classes (just paragraphs)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to parse 'https://projecteuler.net/problem=8' for the middle bit with the number. Since it doesn't have a separate class to select it by, I have used

```
r = requests.get('https://projecteuler.net/problem=8')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
[para1, para2, para3] = (soup.find_all('p'))
```

To separate the paragraphs, but this leaves alot of extra junk (`<p> and <br>`) in there. Is there a command to clear all that out? Is there a better command to do the splitting than I am currently using? Never really done much web crawling in Python...

Comment: The doctype is `html`, you'll want to probably use `'html.parser'` instead of `"lxml"`.  Also, once you have that table of numbers, what's your ideal output?  (NumPy array, or do you just want to print the block?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup.find_all` returns a set of html nodes that contain the html tags; If you want to extract text from the node, you can just use `.text` on each node; applying this on `para2`, gives:

```
para2.text.split()

#['73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934',
# '96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843',
# '85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511',
# '12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557',
# ...
```

Comment: And to return the 1000-digit number: `int(''.join(para2.text.split()))`.

Comment: @BradSolomon Good catch. I thought each line is an individual number. @JordanAustin In the case you want a single number, `para2.text.replace('\n', '')` works as well.